# Should I Make Database Connection With PHP Includes

Tags: php, mysql, database, authentication, include

I've been told that it is unsecure to make database connections inside a PHP includes. For example If I have a login page and add an "include('process.php')" at the top of the page that has a database connection, is that unsecure?

Comment: There is nothing inherently insecure about using includes but perhaps you could show your code and get answers if the code itself is insecure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For example If I have a login page and add an "include('process.php')" at the top of the page that has a database connection, is that unsecure?

No.

Maybe the person who told you this was talking about something else - like including a file  using a dynamic value coming from a GET parameter, or using remote `http://` includes, or as @AlienWebguy mentions, having the password include inside the web root.  But using includes in itself is not insecure.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I needed to know. I wasn't sure if there were any security flaw for seeing the contents of an include file.

Answer (score 1):

It's only insecure if you are storing your passwords literally in your PHP files. They should be declared outside of the web root. That being said, the lack of security is not due to the use of the `include()` function.

Answer (score 0):

In and of itself, no, it is not insecure. How it's implemented inside the include is of course a different story.

Answer (score 0):

That's the way I've always done it.  I make sure that the include is in a different directory that has open permisions and that the directory your writing in has locked permisions. Hopefully that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

This question is way too broad to get a good answer from anyone.  Short answer is no, there's nothing inherently insecure about including a file that connects to a database.  However, if you write code that isn't written properly, then yes it may be insecure to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Since using "include('process.php')" is exactly the same as pasting 'process.php' into the code of the other file, that should not be, per se, a security issue. The insecurity could be in your code, not in the fact the you use the "include". In fact, it could maybe improve the safety of your code, due the reuse.